How to shift/center a tikz grid?
I have this code which draws a 15x10 grid with 10mm cells:
\documentclass[dvipsnames,parskip,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define the grid size
    \def\rows{15}
    \def\cols{10}
    \def\cellsize{10mm}
    
    % Calculate the total width and height of the grid
    \def\gridwidth{\cols*\cellsize}
    \def\gridheight{\rows*\cellsize}

    % Draw the grid
    \draw[step=\cellsize] (0mm,0mm) grid (\gridwidth, \gridheight);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I want to shift the grid to the right (in fact, I want to center it along the x axis and maybe also the y axis).
I tried setting xshift in the square brackets of the \draw command but that did nothing. I also tried using, say (25mm,0mm) or (-25mm,0mm) instead of (0mm,0mm), but that only offset the right end of the grid. It still starts at the margin on the left and it also starts at an incomplete cell (so the grid appears broken).
I tried googling but I can't seem to find how to do this, even though it seems like a such a basic thing.
I am also planning to number the cells of the grid. My current code for this seems to work. I hope the solution for shifting/centering the grid horizontally/vertically won't break it or that it will be easy to fix. This is said code:
    \foreach \y in {14,...,0}
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\z{int(\x+(10*\y))}
            \node at (\x*10mm-5mm,\y*10mm+5mm) {\z};


Wrap tikzpicture with a center environment

The coordinates you use inside a TikZ picture are relative to the TikZ picture itself and have no relation to the placement on the page. This is controlled by where you put the TikZ picture in your diagram. “but that only offset the right end of the grid” → No, it added to the left of the grid. But since the whole picture/grid is typeset by LaTeX it will be left-aligned to your text area. As @Stephen said, center your TikZpicture if you want it to be centered on the line.

This positions the grid relative to (current page.center).  It uses a scope to move the origin.  Note that this tikzpicture has no bounding box.  If you remove the overlay option, the bounding box will include both the grid and the tikzpicture origin (location) in one large rectangle.
\documentclass[dvipsnames,parskip,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \begin{scope}[shift=(current page.center)]
    % Define the grid size
    \def\rows{14}% must be even number
    \def\cols{10}
    \def\cellsize{10mm}
    
    % Calculate the total width and height of the grid
    \def\gridwidth{\cols*\cellsize}
    \def\gridheight{\rows*\cellsize}

    % Draw the grid
    \draw[step=\cellsize] (-0.5*\gridwidth, -0.5*\gridheight) grid (0.5*\gridwidth, 0.5*\gridheight);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

